# many to one conditional thread lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, condition-variable

The problem:
First off, this is a simplified example of my problem, and it is really part of a large framework already programmed by someone else in which i have to adapt my code into.

I have 3 functions. Two of the functions (function1 and function2) are being called by other parts of the program both asynchronously and synchronously. 
My last function (function3) runs continuously, like a while loop, and the only thing it does is to fire an event code on each code iteration. 
I only want this last function to run whenever one of the two other functions have completed an iteration/been called.
I can not change how/when they are called, i can only block the execution of the code and unblock it.

I am fairly new to c++ and i have tried solving this using a mutex, but i have had no luck.
I can add the code, but it really is just like i explained.

```
void function1(){  // this function is called by other parts of the program
//some code
}

void funtion2(){  //this function is also called by other parts of the program
//some other code
}

void function3(){ //this function runs continuously, similar to a while loop with a 1ms sleep in it

fireEvent();//fires an event to run some other code
}
```

So, function3 runs all the time unless blocked, and i would only like to run the function every time one of the other functions have had one run-through. Like i said before, i can not call function3 myself, i can only manipulate the code in the function.

What is the best way of going about this?

After intense googleing i have only come up with conditional variables, semaphore and mutex, but i don't know enough about them to know how i can implement it correctly.

Any help/input/tip is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One thing you're not quite definitive on is whether the handler-code in `function3()` should match the number of invocations of `function1()` and `function2()`. I.e. if `function1()` is invoked twice and `function2()` three times, should the iterative loop in `function3()` fire *exactly* five events with absolution?

Comment: Sorry about that. In reality the 2 functions will always be called at the same time, but it is not always sure that they both will be called, sometimes only one of them. But when both are called, it is at the same time. And in both cases i only want function3 to run once. Like an OR, if one of them runs, then run function3, if both, then still run function3 once.

Comment: Edit to the one above.In reality there will be 16 of these functions that wake up function3. The functions will always be called at the same time, but it is not always sure that all of them will be called, sometimes maybe half, sometimes just one. And in all cases i only want function3 to run once. Like an OR, if one of them runs, then run function3, if more of them run at the same time, then still run function3 only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straigtforward way would be like this:

```
mutex g_mutex;
condition_variable g_cond;
bool flag = false;
void function1(){ // this function is called by other parts of the program
    //some code
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    flag = true;
    g_cond.notify_one();
}

void funtion2(){ //this function is also called by other parts of the program
    //some other code
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    flag = true;
    g_cond.notify_one();
}

void function3(){ //this function runs continuously, similar to a while loop with a 1ms sleep in it
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(g_mutex);
        g_cond.wait(lock, []{return flag;}); // wait here until func1 or func2 have been called
        flag = false;
    }
    fireEvent();//fires an event to run some other code
}

int main() {
// your code goes here
return 0;
}
```

But this will block your `function3` until one of the other twos are called. So it is a change of the behaviour and it adds additional lock contention.

Comment: I haven't tested this code yet, but what will happen if the two functions are called at the same time? Does the notify give an error if the cond-var has been notified already? Please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @trudesagen: No you can notify the condition as often as you want. If no one is waiting for it the notification will get lost. Therefore the bool flag.

Comment: I will test this fully tomorrow, seems like a have some missing libs that i need to fix first. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response. This seems to be working fine for me now, thank you.